# how will I clear my canvas given the code below?

Tags: android, touch-event

This the code of my program:

SingleTouchEvent is the name of my class

i tired using canvas.onDraw but it only change the background. What I want is, clearing the canvas for another drawing.

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();


public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);


}
```

it only changes the color of screen. It does not delete the previous content of the canvas.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // nothing to do
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }


    // Schedules a repaint.
invalidate();


return true;
}



}
```

Comment: Close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729377/android-canvas-how-do-i-clear-delete-contents-of-a-canvas-bitmaps-livin

Comment: where will iplace the canvas.onDraw?

Answer (score 0):

call invalidate(); at the end of onDraw function, it'll keep calling onDraw, after this make a check like:

```
if(isClear)
{
    invalidate();//It'll draw nothing.
}
else
{
    do your drawing..
}
```

Or follow this link:
[How to clear finger paint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338635/how-to-clear-finger-paint/8339678#8339678)