# android: Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK) doesn't work to clear canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a `LinearLayout` whose background color is set to black. In this `LinearLayout`, I have a `View` in which I draw using `Canvas`. Because the `onDraw()` method will be called multiple times, I want to clear what I drew previously when I call `onDraw()` method, thus I use `Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)` to clear the canvas.

But what I get is a black screen without anything even when I draw something new. I can already draw something before I add `Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)` within `onDraw()` method.

EDIT: codes of my `onDraw()` method

```
String value = "";
static Bitmap bitmap;
static Canvas canvas;
public void init(){// this is called by constructor method
  this.setWillNotDraw(false);
  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  canvas = new Canvas();
  canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
  drawGrid();
}
public void drawGrid(){
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
  canvas.drawText(value, somex, somey, paint);
}
public void changeData(String value){
  this.value = value;
  this.postInvalidate();
}
```

Another question, where is the right place I call `Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)`?

Comment: "But what I get is a black screen without anything".  What did you expect to get?

Comment: oh, I want to clear the screen and redraw, but the redraw part cannot be seen

Comment: Please show us your `onDraw()` method, guessing is nothing useful and a waste of time...

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code and it works for me. Clearing the draw on canvas.

```
public void resetBitmapCanvasAndPath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDrawingUtilities.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH,Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT ,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mDrawingUtilities.mCanvas = new Canvas(mDrawingUtilities.mBitmap);
    mDrawingUtilities.mPath = new Path();
}
```

Here's a link similar to your question and have a look at the accepted answer.
[How to clear finger paint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338635/how-to-clear-finger-paint)

Comment: Do you mean to reset the bitmap? It doesn't work either. I end up getting a black screen like using `Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)`. I cannot draw something new.

Comment: well the code works for me. So you need to look at how to implement the same. It clears the draw on canvas and i can draw again onto canvas.

Comment: have a look at the demo code of fingerpaint in android. May be that will help.

Answer (score -2):

use `Color.TRANSPARENT` instead of using `Color.BLACK`

Comment: yes you are right but from your question i understand that you want to make your layout transparent not black

Comment: sorry for that, the layout has to be black